# Can I change a cut command for a sed?

Tags: shell, awk, sed, ksh, cut

I'm writing a script, part of which is formatting a date value into one that is compatbile with SQL*Plus 8.
The date format is:

```
20191115103845
```

And I need to change this string to

```
to_date('2019/11/15:10:38:45', 'yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss')
```

And I use the cut tool:

```
funcion(){
        data=$1
        year=$(echo $data| cut -c1,2,3,4)
        month=$(echo $data | cut -c5,6)
        day=$(echo $data | cut -c7,8)
        hour=$(echo $data| cut -c9,10)
        min=$(echo $data| cut -c11,12)
        sec=$(echo $date | cut -c13,14)
        echo "to_date('"$year"/"$month"/"$day":"$hour":"$min":"$sec"', 'yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss')"
}

funcion $data_to_format
```

(data_to_format=20191115103845)

My issue is that this takes some seconds, and i'm going to use this script for more than thousand files with 100+ dates each one. So I thought that maybe 'sed' command could be better for this.
But I use a ksh88 (old ksh) and the sed does not have -E options and can't make it work.

Can anyone help me please with a old regexp sed solution?

Comment: Take a look with `bash`: `data="20191115103845"; echo "${data:0:4}"`

Comment: You had tagged this [tag:bash] but your text said `ksh88`; I retagged this as [tag:ksh]

Comment: In your code you sometimes have `echo $data` (ends in `a`) and sometimes `echo $date` (ends in `e`).

Comment: The version of sed you have isn't related to which shell you use - sed and bash (or ksh88 or any other shell) are completely different tools.

Comment: I just noticed you said `i'm going to use this script for more than thousand files with 100+ dates each one` - given that, don't do anything shown in any of the answers here as you should be using an awk script to process the files, not a shell script that calls awk (or does anything else) to convert individual strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v s1="\047" -v firstPart="to_date(" -v lastPart="yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss" '
{
  print firstPart s1 substr($0,1,4) "/" substr($0,5,2) "/" substr($0,7,2)":"\
        substr($0,9,2)":"substr($0,11,2)":"substr($0,13,2) s1 ", " s1\
        lastPart s1 ")"
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

- `-v s1="\047"`: Creating variable named `s1` which has value as `'` in it.
- `-v firstPart="to_date("`: Creating variable `firstPart` which has string `to_date(` in it.
- `-v lastPart="yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss"`: Creating variable lastPart which has string `yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss` in it.
- `print`: Using print function to print variables and values.
- `firstPart s1 substr($0,1,4) "/" substr($0,5,2) "/" substr($0,7,2)":"\ substr($0,9,2)":"substr($0,11,2)":"substr($0,13,2) s1 ", " s1\ lastPart s1 ")"`: Printing variables and sub-strings as per OP's requirements here.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Adding a `sed` solution too here, using back reference capability of `sed` here.

```
echo "20191115103845" |
sed 's/\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)/to_date(\x27\1\/\2\/\3:\4:\5:\6\x27, \x27yyyy\/mm\/dd:hh24:mi:ss\x27)/'
```

***OR*** Thanks to tripleee since `\x27` may not be supported in few sed so adding another way of using `'` inside `sed` code.

```
echo "20191115103845" |
sed 's/\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)/to_date('"'"'\1\/\2\/\3:\4:\5:\6'"'"', '"'"'yyyy\/mm\/dd:hh24:mi:ss'"'"')/'
```

Comment: Thank you! This has worked! The final version is:</br>
`echo $data| awk -v s1="\047" -v firstPart="to_date(" -v lastPart="yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss" '
{
  print firstPart s1 substr($0,1,4) "/" substr($0,5,2) "/" substr($0,7,2)":"\
        substr($0,9,2)":"substr($0,11,2)":"substr($0,13,2) s1 ", " s1\
        lastPart s1 ")"
}
'`

Comment: `\x27` is not portable to all `sed` dialects. If it's not available in yours, you can easily substitute e.g. a literal single quote, though you have to understand how the quoting works.  Briefly, `'"single\27quote"'` can be rephrased as `'single'"'"'quote'` where the three quoted strings `'single'`, `"'"`, and `'quote'` are pasted adjacent to each other.

Comment: @tripleee, sure thank you for letting know, I will add that note in solution now.

Answer (score 1):

Probably better still is to use shell built-in parameter expansions all the way.

There is no simple way to do it in a single step, but you can remove a prefix at a time and then process the remaining tail.  In brief, `${variable#pattern}` returns `$variable` with any prefix match on `pattern` removed, and `${variable%pattern}` does the same with a suffix match.

```
funcion(){
    data=${1#[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}
    year=${1%"$data"}
    data=${data#"$year"}
    tail=${data#[0-9][0-9]}
    month=${data%"$tail"}
    data=${data#"$month"}
    tail=${data#[0-9][0-9]}
    day=${data%"$tail"}
    data=${data#"$day"}
    tail=${data#[0-9][0-9]}
    hour=${data%"$tail"}
    data=${data#"$hour"}
    tail=${data#[0-9][0-9]}
    min=${data%"$tail"}
    sec=${tail#"$min"}
    echo "to_date('"$year"/"$month"/"$day":"$hour":"$min":"$sec"', 'yyyy/mm/dd:hh24:mi:ss')"
}
```

This looks cumbersome, but you should find that it is faster than calling an external subprocess (let alone then six, like in your original example).

Answer (score 1):

For efficiency I wouldn't use any external tool for this if you're just converting a string, just change your shell and use bash:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

funcion() {
    local date=$1
    if [[ "$date" =~ ^(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)$ ]]; then
        printf "todate('%s/%s/%s:%s:%s:%s', 'yyyy/mm/dd/hh24:mi:ss')\n" \
            "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" \
            "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" \
            "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}" \
            "${BASH_REMATCH[4]}" \
            "${BASH_REMATCH[5]}" \
            "${BASH_REMATCH[6]}"
    fi
}

funcion '20191115103845'
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
todate('2019/11/15:10:38:45', 'yyyy/mm/dd/hh24:mi:ss')
```

If you're doing that in a loop THEN replace the whole shell loop with one call to awk.